# Por que que eu deveria usar Reflection no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria saber por que que eu deveria usar `Reflection` em JavaScript ao invés dos operadores normais. Eu só soube que existia `Reflection` hoje e eu queria saber por que que seria mais útil usar `Reflection` ao invés de operadores normais.

Um exemplo seria usar `Reflect.deleteProperty(target, key)` invés de `delete target[key]` supondo que `target` é um objeto.

Comment: Defina "operadores normais" e poderia descrever por que acha que o Reflection e os ditos "operadores normais" fazem a mesma coisa?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Um exemplo seria `Reflection.deleteProperty(target, key)` invés de `delete target[key]` isto supondo que `target` é um objeto

Comment: Complete a pergunta com essas informações usando o botão [edit].

Comment: De forma geral não deveria. Pra usar algo precisa ter justificativa. Você tem? Eu vejo uma, mas pode ser porque eu procuro fazer tudo com simplicidade.

Comment: @Maniero Eu não tenho justificação, eu apenas achei a `Reflection` enquanto olhava as docs da Mozilla portanto eu pensei se haveria alguma razão para usá-la invés dos operadores tais como `delete`, `new`, `in` e entre outros.